# How to update the PATH variable in a platform agnostic way using node js

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

i am making a CLI to automate the installation process of a software. I install it in a directory like `$HOME/.software-name/`. Now i would like to know about a platfrom agnostic way to update the system `PATH` environment variable so that in the future the user can run the command easily.

I am not looking for a `os` specific way like `setx` on windows or writing to the `~/.bashrc`. I would prefer a library to do the task or a builtin function.

i know that i can retrieve the env variable using `process.env.variableName` but setting it would not work outside the child process (ie, NodeJS). It does work inside the NodeJS process but that is obviously not what is wanted here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Would using `process.platform` to find the OS, followed by platform specific code to set path using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd work?

Comment: It is basically running it in a shell right? Would It work if I'm on a different shell like fish or zsh for example.

Comment: I am not sure if fish or zsh would read bashrc for path. I would instead check if .zshrc exist and add path there too.

Comment: Then probably it would be a huge pain to make it work everywhere..... Or we could try to leave the user to add the path as well...